# Seeking PyQGIS equivalent to Geopandas or SQL?

Tags: pyqgis, sql, qgis-python-console

Using sql

```
"DBpop2016" = maximum("DBpop2016" , group_by:= "DAUID")
```

OR geopandas

```
print (data.groupby('DAUID') ['DBUID','DBpop2016'].max())
```

I can select the single DB (of which there are several) with max.pop. within multiple DAs.

How can i do this in the Python console with (PyQGIS) with either QGIS3.8 or 3.4?

Answer (score 1):

Install pandas in your QGIS python environment. Im on linux and did the following:

In QGIS find python executable:

```
import sys
sys executable
'/usr/bin/python3'
```

In terminal/command prompt:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install pandas
```

Then you can create a pandas dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

layer = iface.activeLayer()
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=layer.getFeatures(request), columns=[f.name() for f in layer.fields()])

df.groupby('KKOD')['area'].max()
```

[image]